# Re-sizing Footer - activates scrolling but the background image does not Fill/Show when scrolling

Tags: html, css

When I re-size the footer, i.e. make the window browser smaller the page gives me the option to scroll. However, when I scroll the background image of the footer does not display past the original window, leaving a huge white gap...

This is the original footer - no edits
[image: original footer]

Minimizing the browser shows scrolling (which is fine)
[image: scrolling window]

If I then scroll, the background does not render... 
[image: scrolled]

HTML:

```
<div id="footerfix" class="grid_12">
<div id="insidefooterfix" class="grid_12margin">

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footerfix {
color: #C9C9C9;
width: 100%;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
list-style: none;
height: 460px;
padding-bottom: 0;
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/yb7j6PD.png);
background-repeat:repeat;   
}


#insidefooterfix {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
height: 380px;
margin-bottom: 0;

}

.grid_12margin {
display:inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
}

.grid_12 {
display:inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
/*margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;*/
}

.container_12 .grid_12 {
width:100%;
/*width:98.0%;*/
}
```

Code here (simplified without information but all CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/UVvM2/ (but doesn't show any problems here?)

Here is FULL which does show problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UVvM2/2/

Comment: Please add information with footer.

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya thank you for your response. Here is full fiddle which actually demostrates the problem when you try and resize http://jsfiddle.net/UVvM2/2/

Comment: in your JSfiddle you've got lots of min and max widths of 960px, so it won't go smaller than 960px. switch these for % and you should find it works better

Comment: @Ben the footer is working as I want it to. I did try changing the settings to % an it hasn't resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The 100% width is relative to your screen, try to add the background-color in your body :

```
<body clas="gray-bg">
   <div id = "footer-fix"> , etc .
```

CSS :

> .gray-bg{
>   background-color:#2D2D2D;
>   }

Comment: thank you for your reply. This does fix the problem, but it then creates 10 other problems (causing all my other content to lose the background color. Oddly I have the <body> then a container div inside the body and even if I try and change the background of the container div (which is a child of body), the background is still overlapped by the body (parent). Thank you anyway for your input. It almost fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Looking likes see this Below link..

[Reference link](http://jsfiddle.net/m9qn9/)

```
#insidefooterfix, #disclaimerfix {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;  
    margin-right: auto;
}
#footerfix {
    color: #C9C9C9; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    list-style: none;
    height: 460px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background-image:url(../img/index/footer/pixelpatterns.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
#insidefooterfix {
     display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 20px auto;

    text-align: center;
    height: 380px; 
}
/*settings for social media buttons*/
 #insidefooterfixtermsplusbuttons li {
    display: inline;
    color: #C9C9C9;
}
#insidefooterfixone h5, #insidefooterfixtwo h5, #insidefooterfixthree h5, #insidefooterfixfour h5 {
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#insidefooterfixone ul, #insidefooterfixtwo ul, #insidefooterfixthree ul, #insidefooterfixfour ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #C9C9C9;
}
#insidefooterfixone li, #insidefooterfixtwo li, #insidefooterfixthree li, #insidefooterfixfour li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #C9C9C9;
}




#disclaimerfix {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;    
}
#disclaimerfix p {
    text-align:center;
    color: #C9C9C9;
}
#insidefooterfixone {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
#insidefooterfixtwo {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
#insidefooterfixthree {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
#insidefooterfixfour {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
.container_12 .grid_12 {
    width:100%;
    /*width:98.0%;*/
}
.grid_12margin {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.grid_12 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    /*margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;*/
}
```